# React on Form.Shown event in UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I have created custom control. I would like to perform in my custom control after that Form.Shown event. I have tried in **Control.GotFocus** event which has triggered before that **Form.Shown** event. I want to make the changes in my control after that **Form.Shown** event.

Is it possible? If yes means, please suggest me how to do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You could register to the event:

```
public class MyControl : UserControl
{
       // you need a reference to the hosting Form
       public MyControl(Form frmHost)
       {
            frmHost.Shown += FormHost_Shown;
       }

       private void FormHost_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           // Do your work
       }
}
```

When you the create an instance of your control, just pass a reference to the hosting form:

```
this.Controls.Add(new MyControl(this));
```

If you need a parameterless constructor you could make the hosting `Form` a property of your control and set that property before the `Shown` event happens:

```
public class MyControl : UserControl
{
       private Form frmHost;

       public Form FrmHost
       {
           get
           {
               return frmHost;
           }

           set
           {
               frmHost = value;
               frmHost.Shown += FormHost_Shown;
           }
       }

       private void FormHost_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           // Do your work
       }
}

public class MyForm : Form
{
        public MyForm()
        {
             InitializeComponent();
             // User control was created elsewhere (perhaps in the designer)
             myUserControl.FrmHost = this;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/order-of-events-in-windows-forms) order of events when activating for the first time a windows forms is the following:

1. `Control.HandleCreated`
2. `Control.BindingContextChanged`
3. `Form.Load`
4. `Control.VisibleChanged`
5. `Form.Activated`
6. `Form.Shown`

As you can see, `Shown` is the last fired event. You would need to implement your own event in your custom base `Form`:

```
public event EventHandler AfterShwon;

protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
{
     base.OnShow(e);
     OnAfterShown(e);
}

protected virtual void OnAfterShown(e)
{
     AfterShwon?.Invoke(this, e);
}
```